# Write variable into name attribute of the anchor selector

Tags: jquery

How do I write a variable into the value of the name attribute of the anchor selector?

```
$("a[name=$hash]").addClass('open');
```

Comment: Like this? `$("a[name=" + $hash + "]").addClass('open');`

Comment: What is `$hash`? Is it php varible or jquery variable?

Comment: jquery and I meant to write `hash` as in `window.location.hash`

Answer (score -2):

If you write this code in php page then you can write as following

```
$("a[name=<?php echo $hash; ?>]").addClass('open');
```

Comment: OP not mentioned that he is using PHP